# Where I must put PreparedStatament in a transaction

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions, prepared-statement

Suppose I want to save remove two element in two different table, so I must create transaction. My problem is where I must put `PreparedStatement` elements? I must put in this way (I mean in the transaction)

```
connection_database.setAutoCommit(false);
connection_database.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE);
PreparedStatement p1.......
PreparedStatement p2;
p1.execute();
p2.execute();
connessione_db.commit();
connessione_db.setAutoCommit(true);
```

Or can I put it in this way?

```
PreparedStatement p1.......
PreparedStatement p2;
connection_database.setAutoCommit(false);
connection_database.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE);

p1.execute();
p2.execute();
connessione_db.commit();
connessione_db.setAutoCommit(true);
```

1. the first way creates the `PreparedStatement` is in the transaction
2. the second way create the `PreparedStatement` is out the transaction.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: I guess this is a self-answering question if you try to make real code from the examples (Spoiler: `Connection` is a factory for `PreparedStatement`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a conforming JDBC implementation you can use either order: a prepared statement has a lifetime longer than a transaction and should be reusable after transaction commits.

However, it may be more efficient to first disable auto-commit before preparing the statements, depending on the driver and database system. This may depend on whether or not the driver needs a transaction when preparing the statement. If the driver needs a transaction when preparing, then disabling auto-commit after prepare may have started (and committed) one or two transactions in the course of preparing those two statements, but if you prepare them after disabling auto-commit, the prepare could use the same transaction as subsequently used for the actual execution.

Answer (score 0):

Statement objects can be shared, also they can be cached. So there is no problem with the code you have provided. Just make sure they are put in a try catch block, so if not successful, it will be rolled back.

Flat transactions are rolled back if not successful as is the case with you. Nested Transactions are committed from one point to the other point, so can be rolled back only partially. You can go with the second piece of code. No need to make the transaction serializable, try to lock based on the timestamp depending on whether you are doing a read or write and your requirements.

Comment: Rather confusing, i don't see anything in the question related to "nested transactions". And i dont see where some "lock based on Timestamp" (whatever that means) would help here...

Comment: Serialization is done because he intends to maintain the Atomicity of Transaction. So to maintain the same if there is a race condition the same can be locked based on the same timestamp of threads racing against each other. If during write Serializable or atomicity has to be achieved, then only when same timestamps are noted, those specific reads can be locked. This is what I meant. Coming to nested transaction, Nested Transactions are atomically committed before starting another transaction. he was doing two transactions here. hence he had a doubt if that can be done like that.